# How do I use generic typing with PyQt subclass without metaclass conflicts?

Tags: python, pyqt5, metaclass, typing, pyside2

I had tried the `abc.ABCMeta` with sip wrapper type, and it works well when subclass with `abc.ABC`.

```
class QABCMeta(wrappertype, ABCMeta):
    pass

class WidgetBase(QWidget, metaclass=QABCMeta):
    ...

class InterfaceWidget(WidgetBase, ABC):
    ...

class MainWidget(InterfaceWidget):
    ...
```

But it is not works on `typing.Generic`.

```
class QGenericMeta(wrappertype, GenericMeta):
    pass

class WidgetBase(QWidget, Generic[T], metaclass=QGenericMeta):
    ...

class GenericWidget(WidgetBase[float]):
    ...
```

It raised:

```
line 980, in __new__
    self if not origin else origin._gorg)
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to sip.wrappertype object
```

I expected it to use generic subclass as usual:

```
class TableBase(QTableWidget, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def raw_item(self, row: int) -> T:
        ...
    def data(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        yield from (self.raw_item(row) for row in range(self.rowCount()))

class MainTable(TableBase[float]):
    def raw_item(self, row: int) -> float:
        return float(self.item(row, 1).text())  # implementation

table = MainTable()
for data in table.data():
    data: float
```

But the `data` is still `Any` when without inherit `Generic[T]`.

Can it solved with PEP 560 to do type checking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I found the answer.

Since the metaclass of `typing.Generic` is `abc.ABC`, it should based on `abc.ABCMeta` too. But this is only works with Python 3.7 or above.

And then, just use `type(QObject)` instead of `sip.wrappertype`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from abc import abstractmethod, ABC, ABCMeta
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Iterator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget

QObjectType = type(QObject)
T = TypeVar('T')


class QABCMeta(QObjectType, ABCMeta):
    pass


class BaseWidget(QTableWidget, Generic[T], metaclass=QABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def raw_item(self, row: int) -> T:
        ...

    def data(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        yield from (self.raw_item(row) for row in range(self.rowCount()))


class TestWidget(BaseWidget[float], ABC):  # optional inherit ABC.

    def raw_item(self, row: int) -> float:
        return float(self.item(row, 1).text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = TestWidget()
    for f in w.data():
        pass
```

This code is works for PyCharm IDE, the annotation of variable `f` is `float`.

When change `PyQt5` to `PySide2`, it also works!